# Load spread metric issues in power amplifiers

Tags: rf, power-amplifier

Power amplifier saturation or maximum power depends a lot on the load seen by the collector or the drain of the amplifier. If the load impedance varies across frequency, how serious is this in terms of the PA performance? I would be particularly interested to know the impact of load spread on class F or inverse F power amplifiers.

Comment: Why don't you simulate to find out?

Comment: The proper variables would be the spectral density losses for s11 & s21. This appears to be well documented.